# serialized parameters with jquery for ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help to prepare parameters for $.ajax submit.

I have multiple pairs of html inputs (i pairs):

```
> <input type="hidden" value="31" name="product_id"> <input
> type="hidden" value="3" name="quantity">
> 
> <input type="hidden" value="34" name="product_id"> <input
> type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
```

if I use this jquery code:

```
   function send(){      

   var parameter1 =$("input[name$='product_id']").serialize();
   var parameter2 = $("input[name$='quantity']").serialize();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', 
   data: parameter1+'&'+parameter2  
  });
};
```

I send parameters like this:

> product_id=31&product_id=30&quantity=2&quantity=2

How pass parameters like this:

> product_id=31&quantity=2&product_id=30&quantity=2

Thanks

Comment: Use an array `<input type="hidden" value="31" name="product_id[]">`

Comment: will it make difference ? in the end you will be getting them by $_POST[the respective id] only, the sequence is not a problem in any way I guess

Answer (score 0):

if you want parse them in same order they are in html do

```
data = '';
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
    data += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).attr('value');'
});
```

Comment: even if the sorse is change "product_id=31&quantity=2&product_id=30&quantity=2", the parameters ar send in this order
 product_id 31
product_id 30
quantity 2
quantity 2

Comment: maybe your js is cached, try refresh it with ctrl+f5. anyway it's not a good idea to send parameters with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Do following change

In html

```
<form id="frm">
<input type="hidden" value="31" name="product_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="quantity[]">
<input type="hidden" value="34" name="product_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity[]">
</form>
```

in js

```
function send(){      

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', 
  data: jQuery('#frm').serialize()  
 });
};
```

you will get value in global $_POST

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function send(){      
    var data = {
        parameter1:$("input[name$='product_id']").val(),
        parameter2:$("input[name$='quantity']").val()
    };



  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', 
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   success : function(msg){
   // your code here       
   },
   error : function(msg){
   // your code here
   },  
  });
};
```